# Is it possible to make conditions in ASCII?

Tags: ascii

I am working on a software that needs commands in ASCII to define alert thresholds.
These thresholds, correspond to a quantity in littre according to a number of gas tank connected each others.

### Examples :

-If it's 1 or 2 tanks the threshold will be 30 L and the ASCII code is S6350130 ("S635" to set up, 01 for the first tank, 30 for 30 litters).

-If it's 3 tanks the threshold will be 45 L and the ASCII code is S6350145 ("S635" to set up, 01 for the first tank, 45 for 45 litters).

-If it's 4 or 5 tanks the threshold will be 60 L and the ASCII code is S6350130 ("S635" to set up, 01 for the first tank, 60 for 60 litters).

-If it's 6 or 7 tanks the threshold will be 80 L and the ASCII code is S6350130 ("S635" to set up, 01 for the first tank, 80 for 80 litters).

My problem is I have to repeat the command for each tank, and I want to know if it is possible make conditions in ASCII to write only one command?

I hope it is clear.

### Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense.  And you've left litter everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

ASCII is a way to encode text in bytes.

It is not a programming language. It has no means of expressing logic.

Just about every programming language can be expressed in ASCII and can manipulate ASCII encoded data, so you can pick any programming language you like and write your logic in that.

Comment: Ok, thank you.So ASCII works a bit like SQL?

Comment: No. SQL is language for manipulating databases. ASCII just lets you describe things like `A` in `1`s and `0`s.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott — I've edited the answer to make it clearer.